# How to upload image to cloudinary directly from node express app without making any directly in server

Tags: upload, mern, cloudinary

How to upload image to cloudinary directly from node express app without making any directly in server

i tried many many ways but not find the answer i tried but they are save temp file on server which i cant beacause vercel not allow to make new directly on server
so i want to upload picture without uploading on server

Comment: You could use a remote URL:
`
const remoteFileUrl = 'https://example.com/remote-file.jpg'; // Replace with the actual remote file URL

cloudinary.uploader.upload(remoteFileUrl, { public_id: 'desired_public_id' }, (error, result) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error('Error uploading remote file:', error);
  } else {
    console.log('Remote file uploaded successfully:', result);
  }
});
`

Answer (score 0):

Assets can only be uploaded using the Cloudinary SDK on the server side. So, if you want to upload an image directly using Node Express, you will need to make a direct call to the Cloudinary REST API. Something like:

```
https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<cloud name>/<resource_type>/upload
```

You can learn more about it in the [Cloudinary documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#uploading_with_a_direct_call_to_the_rest_api).